# How can I query adjacent hierarchical data from two tables where one row is a category and the rest are contents of that category?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, hierarchy

*DISCLAIMER*: I am a linguist and not a computer scientist. I am familiar with programming, but I am not an expert. This project is for a large lexicon of an endangered language. I need to categorize about 1000 lexemes, such that I can visually see which words are missing and might be added.

---

I have two tables in MySQL.

1. Lexicon Table
2. Categories Table

Each record (row) in the lexicon table has a parent id value (**pid**) corresponding to the id of the categories table (which I have renamed **folder**).

I designed this according to the adjacency model (I need the flexabilty to change the tree easily).

**categories**

```
| folder |     name    | pfolder |
+--------+-------------+---------+
| 1      | Animals     | NULL    |
| 2      | Wild        | 1       |
| 3      | Domestic    | 1       |
```

**lexicon**

```
| id     | pid   | word        | translation |
+--------+-------+-------------+-------------+
| 1      | 3     | Hund        | dog         |
| 2      | 2     | Rentier     | reindeer    |
| 3      |       | Maus        | Mouse       |
```

---

**GOAL**

```
| main    | main_content  |  sub1     | sub1_content | sub2      | sub2_content |
+---------+---------------+-----------+--------------+-----------+--------------+
| Animals | NULL          | Domestic  | Hund         | NULL      | NULL         |
| Animals | NULL          | Wild      | Rentier      | NULL      | NULL         |
| Animals | Maus          | NULL      | NULL         | NULL      | NULL         |
```

**Sample Query**

I do not know how to do this and I cannot simply follow [this tutorial](http://sqllessons.com/categories.html) because I have multiple tables.

Shouldn't this simple query work?

```
SELECT main.name  AS main
FROM categories AS main
    LEFT JOIN hd FROM lexicon ON lexicon.pid = categories.main
```

**Ultimately**

I would like to end up with a nice list of organized lexemes. Here I used bold for folders and italics for list items.

- **Animals**

  - **Wild**

    - *Rentier*
  - **Domestic**

    - *Hund*
  - *Maus*

This data will be printed using xelatex. For the sake of simplicity, I kept the example tables above to a minimum. The actually queries for the lexicon table will include the `lexeme`, `orthographic word`, and `phonetic word` (in the International Phonetic Alphabet).

Comment: I'm not sure but there can be a conflit with the 2 alliases `main`. Your query seems to be syntaxicaly good but your are going to got only `name` col, not the 6 cols listed in your GOAL table; If you want to know if your query works, try it :-)

Comment: @Marcassin Of course I tried it, but I should have mentioned that it does not work. You may be right about the aliases, however, I do not that think that is the only issue. As stated under Sample Query, "I don't know how to do this" is referring to the **GOAL** table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit complicated, but I think it gets what you need. One change tough, you need to put pid=1 in Maus row in Lexicon if you want to show it under Animals.

```
SELECT
   COALESCE(c3.name, c2.name, c1.name) as main
  ,CASE WHEN (c3.name is null and c2.name is null) then lex.word end as main_content
  ,CASE WHEN (c3.name is null and c2.name is not null) then c1.name 
        WHEN (c3.name is not null and c2.name is not null) then c2.name end as sub1
  ,CASE WHEN (c3.name is null and c2.name is not null) then lex.word end as sub1_content
  ,CASE WHEN (c3.name is not null and c2.name is not null) then c1.name end as sub2
  ,CASE WHEN (c3.name is not null and c2.name is not null) then lex.word end as sub2_content
FROM
  Lexicon lex
LEFT JOIN 
  Categories c1 ON lex.pid = c1.folder
LEFT JOIN
  Categories c2 on c1.pfolder = c2.folder
LEFT JOIN
  Categories c3 on c2.pfolder = c3.folder
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8495e/32) - I have also added one more subcategory (WildCats under Wild) to test if SUB2 is getting correctly?

Comment: Could you please explain what "lex" is? I gave you an upvote for your nice work!

Comment: @macmadness86 "lex" is an alias I gave to table Lexicon to shorten it when used (lex.Word instead Lexicon.Word). You can always do that to make your queries easier to write or in case like c1, c2, c3 (also aliases) - you have to do it - to make a difference between different joins on same table.